# ¿Cómo hacer click a link html por atributo title en Selenium IDE?, porque no tiene id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selenium, selenium-ide

Estoy automatizando mis pruebas pero ocupo hacer click en un link que no contiene el atributo id, pero si tiene atributo title.

¿Cómo puedo en la aplicacion Selenium IDE generar ese click para el link?

Código en el IDE generado en tipo HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://10.28.114.26/" />
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=txt_usr</td>
    <td>9595959</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeValue</td>
    <td>id=txt_usr</td>
    <td>num_emp</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=txt_pwd</td>
    <td>3625</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=btn_action</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>a[title=Solicitud de Compra Medios]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Pero el último evento del click para entrar a la opción `Solicitud de Compra Medios` no funciona ya que dice que no existe el elemento al buscarlo con  el filtro `a[title=Solicitud de Compra Medios]`

Comment: Qué quieres hacer exactamente? Obtener el texto del enlace? Agregue también el código a su pregunta para que podamos ver mejor lo que está pasando.

Comment: Selenium lo que hace es automatizar pruebas en el navegador, y hasta ahorita he programado eventos para que se loguee al sistema todo bien, pero el detalle que para entrar a una opción ya logueado no logro obtener el link de la opción ya que no cuenta con el atributo id.

Answer (score 0):

No entendí bien si era para obtener el `title="título"` tag, o el `título` significando el texto de dentro de el elemento, así hice para ambos:

```js
// El primero busca si contiene un texto igual dentro del elemento
// El segundo busca en el title=""
var $solicitud = $('table td:contains("Solicitud de Compra Medios")');
var $solicitud2 = $('td[title*="Solicitud de Compra Medios"]');

// Procura en cada "table td"
$('table td').each(function () {
    // Si alguno de estos coinciden
    if ( $(this).is($solicitud) || $(this).is($solicitud2) ) {
        // hace algo aquí
        $(this).addClass('red'); // Como por ejemplo añadir una clase roja
        return false; // return false para dejar de buscar cuando se encuentra
    }
});
```

```css
.red{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>click</td>
            <td title="Solicitud de Compra Medios">a[title=Solicitud de Compra Medios]</td>
            <td>random</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Puede hacer los cambios necesarios para su necesidades como quitar uno de los títulos si quieres etc. También recomiendo crear y apuntar un identificador (`#id > td`) o algo así, en lugar de `table td`.

Comment: Pero tu lo estas haciendo en programacion jquery, yo ocupo que mediante la aplicacion Selenium IDE que es un software para testers, la programacion para obtener los elementos cambia un poco a como tradicionalmente lo hace jquery.

Comment: Anexo  la liga del software [http://www.seleniumhq.org/]

Comment: Pensé que podrías utilizar jQuery, como la pregunta tiene la etiqueta :\

Comment: La encontré y la solución era: event: click, target: css=a[title="Solicitud de Compra Medios"] > div.box.col1 > div. Ya con eso el software automaticamente da click sobre el link.